# I need .bat script, that will create folder in directory of script, which name contains current date and additional string

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need .bat script, that will create folder in directory of script, which name conatins current date and adidional string. The folder should look like that: **2017-02-26 SK**. I managed to make a new folder with date in name, but I don't know how to add SK at the end. My script looks like this:

```
@echo off
set user = SK
mkdir %date:/=%
end
```

Comment: `set "user=SK"` (no spaces around `=`), then `mkdir "%date:/=%%user%"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you imply your code already does the date part, then all you need in your batch file is:

```bat
@IF NOT EXIST "%~dp0%DATE:/=-% SK\" MD "%~dp0%DATE:/=-% SK"
```

However if you cannot guarantee the format of `%DATE%` then use this:

```bat
@FOR /F "SKIP=1 DELIMS=" %%A IN ('WMIC OS GET LOCALDATETIME'
) DO @FOR %%B IN (%%~nA) DO @SET "VAR=%%B"
@IF NOT EXIST "%~dp0%VAR:~,4%-%VAR:~4,2%-%VAR:~6,2% SK\" (
    @MD "%~dp0%VAR:~,4%-%VAR:~4,2%-%VAR:~6,2% SK")
@CD /D "%~dp0%VAR:~,4%-%VAR:~4,2%-%VAR:~6,2% SK"
```

Comment: second solution workes perfect! Could you tell me how to cd to that new folder, so I can expand my script for creating another folders within it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the two variables together, put quotes around the `set` command and replace the `/` with `-`

**Updated script:**

```
@echo off
set "user=SK"
set "D=%date:~3%"
md "%D:/=-% %user%"
end
```

Would output

> 26-02-17 SK

Comment: Yeah, but I need date format as shown in the question, so variable must remain %date:/=%. Now it works perfect! Many thanks!

Comment: @s-kaczmarek, in Sam's defense your example in your description had dashes. **2017-02-26 SK**

Comment: @Sam Your solution dosn't work well on windows 10. It gives me folder name in format: mm.yyyy

Answer (score 0):

```
:: Assume format of %date% is "ddd MM/DD/YYYY"
:: Year:  remove the first 10 letters
set YEAR=%date:~10%

:: Month: remove first 4 and last 8 letters
set MO=%date:~4,-8%

:: Day:   remove first 7 and last 5 letters
set DAY=%date:~7,-5%

:: Format the output.
echo %YEAR%-%MO%-%DAY% SK
```

Comment: Maybe use a FOR /F command instead, so that you can take advantage of the TOKENS and DELIMS options.